# Django showing incorrect record value after search

Tags: django, django-tables2

I have a problem with listing data using `django` and [django-tables2](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) that I can't quite figure out.

**Scenario:**

I have a view that displays a list of records. Within this view is also a search box for searching a particular record (Household). Each record displayed has a field (Household size) which is an aggregate count of other records (Person) within it. i.e. HouseHold 1 has 5 persons in it.

The problem is that, when the page is initially loaded, the correct household record size is displayed. For example, using the example I gave above, it will display household size 5 for HouseHold 1. See image below and note the household size of the first record.

[image: Correct Household size]

But when I enter a search term for a particular Household record, the returned result always displays the square of the household size i.e. 25 in my case above (5*5). See image below:

[image: Incorrect Household size]

Can someone please help me figure out where this value is coming from?

Below is my code:

***urls.py***

```
from apps.org.urls import office_url
from lib.security import secure_url as sec

... # Non-relevant code removed

sec(office_url('/household/list/$'),
    registration_views.HouseholdList.as_view(),
    name='household.list'),
```

***views.household.py***

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import transaction
from django.db.models import Count
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django_tables2 import tables  

from apps.registration.models import Household, Person
from lib.views import CoreListView

... # Non-relevant code left out for brevity and clarity

class HouseholdTable(tables.Table):
    name = DetailUrlColumn()
    location = tables.Column()
    household_size = tables.Column(verbose_name=_("Household size"))
    registration_date = tables.Column()
    registration_user = tables.Column(verbose_name='Registered by')
    document_id = DocumentListColumn(_('Document ID'), accessor='recipient_candidate', orderable=False)
    action = ActionColumn(orderable=False,
        actions=(
            ("delete", Household.get_delete_url, "btn-warning", "icon-remove-sign"),
            ("edit", Household.get_detail_url, "btn-info", "icon-edit"),
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        order_by = ("name")
        empty_text = _("no household to display")


class HouseholdList(SelectedOfficeMixin, CoreListView):
    template_name = 'registration/beneficiary/list.html'
    model = Household
    table_class = HouseholdTable
    permissions = ['registration.view_household']
    search_fields = ('name', 'members.documents.document_num')

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Annotate so that the queryset can be ordered by household size."""
        return self.selected_office.households.with_related_members().annotate(household_size=Count('members'))

    def get_doc_url(self):
        doc_root_url = super(HouseholdList, self).get_doc_url()
        return urlparse.urljoin(doc_root_url, 'how_to_register_a_new_beneficiary_household.html')
```

***lib.views.py***

```
... # Non-relevant code left out

class CoreSearchMixin(object):
    """Subclasses must define search_fields = [field_1, ...field_n]
    where the field is a string, the name of a field, and can contain the following prefix characters:

    '^': the search field must start with the search term, case insensitive
    '=': the search field must exactly equal the search term, case insensitive
    '@': full-text search

    If no prefix is given, any string that contains the search field will match.
    """
    search_fields = None
    search_form_class = SearchForm

    @cachedproperty
    def search_form(self):
        return self.search_form_class(getattr(self.request, self.request.method))

    def get_query_help_message(self):
        """Returns a comma separated list of fields that are used in the search, to help the user
        create a search.
        """
        fields = []
        if self.search_fields:
            for search_field in self.search_fields:
                field = get_field_from_path(self.model, search_field)
                fields.append(field.verbose_name.title())
        return ",".join(fields)

    def get_filtered_queryset(self, queryset):
        if self.search_form.is_valid():
            self.query = self.search_form.cleaned_data['q']
        else:
            self.query = None
        if self.search_fields and self.query:
            orm_lookups = (construct_search(str(search_field).replace('.', '__'))
                           for search_field in self.search_fields)
            chained_or_queries = None
            for bit in self.query.split():
                or_queries = (models.Q(**{orm_lookup: bit})
                              for orm_lookup in orm_lookups)
                if chained_or_queries:
                    chained_or_queries = itertools.chain(chained_or_queries, or_queries)
                else:
                    chained_or_queries = or_queries
            return queryset.filter(reduce(operator.or_, chained_or_queries))
        else:
            return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return super(CoreSearchMixin, self).get_context_data(
            search_form=self.search_form,
            query_help_message=self.get_query_help_message(),
            search_fields=self.search_fields,
            **kwargs
        )


class CoreListView(CoreSearchMixin, ListView):
    """Displays a simple searchable list.

    Subclasses must define search fields as per CoreSearchMixin
    """
    template_name = 'cv/generic/list.html'
    table_class = None
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_table_class(self):
        return self.table_class

    def get_table(self, filtered_queryset):
        return self.get_table_class()(filtered_queryset)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        table = self.get_table(self.get_filtered_queryset(self.get_queryset()))
        table.paginate(page=self.request.GET.get('page', 1), per_page=self.paginate_by)
        RequestConfig(self.request, paginate=False).configure(table)
        return super(CoreListView, self).get_context_data(table=table, **kwargs)
```

What I'm I missing here?

Comment: reading your question I thought this problems comes from a bad aggregation annotation due to over join tables. But I see than `household_size` is a table in your `household` model. It isn't?

Comment: `household_size` is just a field. The `Person` model has the following field: `household = models.ForeignKey(Household, related_name='members', blank=True, null=True)`, then using the `Household` model, we can do reverse lookup to get the number of persons that belong to this Household.

Comment: Then, it is a kind of materialized computed field. That is? In your wrong picture, how you get value 25? From materialized field or from annotate expression?

Comment: Actually, I have evaluated this and seen the SQL queries formed and it is due to the `JOIN` in the tables. The SQL generated uses a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, which results in the wrong values. If I change that to an `INNER JOIN`, it returns the correct results.